# Configure autofac to ignore constructors marked as obsolete

Tags: c#, .net, autofac, obsolete

Is it possible to easily configure autofac so it will only resolve using non-obsolete constructors?

eg for a class with a helper constructor for non-DI code,

```
public class Example {

    public Example(MyService service) {
        // ...
    }

    [Obsolete]
    public Example() {
        service = GetFromServiceLocator<MyService>();
        // ...
    }
}

// ....

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Example>();
// no MyService defined.
var container = builder.Build();

// this should throw an exception
var example = container.Resolve<Example>();
```

asking autofac to resolve Example if we haven't registered MyService, should fail.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't believe there is an *out of the box* way to configure Autofac to ignore `Obsolete` constructors.  However, Autofac is so good, there is always a way to get it done :)  Here are two options:

**Option 1.  Tell Autofac which Constructor to use**

Do this using the [`UsingConstructor` registration extension](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Autowiring#Choosing_Constructors) method.

```csh
builder.RegisterType<Example>().UsingConstructor(typeof(MyService));
```

**Option 2.  Provide a custom `IConstructorFinder` to `FindConstructorsWith`**

Autofac has a registration extension method called `FindConstructorsWith`.  You can pass a custom `IConstructorFinder` to one of the two overloads.  You could write a simple `IConstructorFinder` called `NonObsoleteConstructorFinder` that will only return constructors *without* the Obsolete attribute.

I have written this class and added a working version of your sample.  You can [view the full code](https://github.com/bentayloruk/AutofacAnswers/blob/master/AutofacAnswers/SoAnswer6407530.cs) and use it as inspiration.  *IMO option this is the more elegant option.*  I have added it to my [AutofacAnswers](https://github.com/bentayloruk/AutofacAnswers) project on GitHub.

*Note:  The other overload takes BindingFlags.  I don't think you can specify attribute requirements using `BindingFlags`.  However, you may want to check that.*

Comment: Awesome answer :) the example repository is a great idea!

Comment: @Nic Thanks!  Awesome container :)  I just added you as a collaborator on AutofacAnswers (should an urge to commit arise).

Comment: Yes, thank you for taking the time for building up such a great answer!

Comment: @nick-sonneveld my pleasure.  I was not aware of FindConstructorsWith when I wrote the original answer so I got to learn something too.   @nicholas-blumhardt has done all the hard work!

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension to bentayloruk's answer. I tried his **Option 2** but it didn't work. Soon I noticed that this is because I'm using AutoFac Interceptors. AutoFac passes the proxy class type to the constructor finder but these constructors don't have the attributes defined on the constructors in the underlying class.

To make this work my code compares the constructor signatures of both classes to find the "correct" constructor and checks if the attribute is present.

```
public class NonObsoleteConstructorFinder : IConstructorFinder
{
    private readonly DefaultConstructorFinder _defaultConstructorFinder = new DefaultConstructorFinder();

    public ConstructorInfo[] FindConstructors(Type targetType)
    {
        // Find all constructors using the default finder
        IEnumerable<ConstructorInfo> constructors = _defaultConstructorFinder.FindConstructors(targetType);

        // If this is a proxy, use the base type
        if (targetType.Implements<IProxyTargetAccessor>())
        {
            // It's a proxy. Check for attributes in base class.
            Type underlyingType = targetType.BaseType;
            List<ConstructorInfo> constructorList = new List<ConstructorInfo>();

            // Find matching base class constructors
            foreach (ConstructorInfo proxyConstructor in constructors)
            {
                Type[] parameterTypes = proxyConstructor.GetParameters()
                                                        .Select(pi => pi.ParameterType)
                                                        .Skip(1)    // Ignore first parameter
                                                        .ToArray();

                ConstructorInfo underlyingConstructor = underlyingType.GetConstructor(parameterTypes);

                if (underlyingConstructor != null &&
                    !underlyingConstructor.HasAttribute<ObsoleteAttribute>())
                {
                    constructorList.Add(proxyConstructor);
                }
            }

            constructors = constructorList;
        }
        else
        {
            // It's not a proxy. Check for the attribute directly.
            constructors = constructors.Where(c => !c.HasAttribute<ObsoleteAttribute>());
        }

        return constructors.ToArray();
    }
}
```

**Note 1:** `Skip(1)` is required because the first constructor argument of the proxy is of type `IInterceptor[]`. This is used by AutoFac to pass the interceptors.

**Note 2:** `targetType.Implements<IProxyTargetAccessor>()` and `underlyingConstructor.HasAttribute<ObsoleteAttribute>()` are extension methods provided by the Fasterflect library.